# Typescript how to restrict function arguments which depend on each other

Tags: typescript

We have a type (let's call it `Parent`) which is a large object of mostly fields which look like `key: string`, but some fields look like `key: SomeChildType[]`.  Let's say `SomeChildType = {name: string}`.

I want to write a function which takes a `primaryField` (top level key), a `secondaryField` (i.e. a key of `SomeChildType`), and an `object` of type `Parent` and return the list of values which can be gotten by `object[primaryKey].map(item => item[secondaryKey])`.

The issue is that I'm not good at typescript, and I can't figure out how to appease it.

I want to write a function something like:

```
// This is used to restrict primaryKey to only keys of T whose values are lists of objects, and seems to work
type ObjListKeyOf<T> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends object[] ? K : never}[keyof T]

const objInListRetriever = (object: Parent, primaryKey: ObjListKeyOf<Parent>, secondaryKey: string) => {
    // Eventually:
    return object[primaryKey].map(el => el.secondaryKey)
}
```

As you can maybe imagine, TS does not like that I'm attempting to access `object[primaryKey][0][secondaryKey]` because `secondaryKey` can be any string.  It needs to be restricted to only keys of whatever object makes up the list accessed with `object[primaryKey]`.

Has anyone encountered a problem similar to this?  I'm pretty new to typescript, so I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our IDEs and immediately get to work on the issue you're mentioning.  Right now we'd have to turn your verbal descriptions of your issue into code first, and hope we did so properly (did we manage to get TS to "not like" our code the same way?  What is that way?  Is there a specific error message?), just to get started.  Would you mind [edit]ing your question to include such a [mre]?